# Find accurate approximate contour of a warped card with rounded corners with OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, contour, emgucv, edge-detection

I have written an algorithm to find and extract a Magic card in an image based on using OpenCV functions FindContours and ApproxPolyDP. Essentially, I clean up the image (blur, adaptive threshold, etc.), find all of the contours, find the largest one that is approximately rectangular, then warp perspective of the found contour to a known shape. The problem I am having is the ApproxPolyDP doesn't accurately follow the edges of the card, and can slice off the edges when WarpPerspective is applied.

Here is the algorithm:

```
    private Mat ExtractCard(Mat image)
    {
        CvInvoke.Imwrite(Path.Join(Path.GetTempPath(), "output_orig.png"), image);

        Mat temp = image.Clone();

        Mat gray = new();
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

        Mat blurred = new();
        CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(gray, blurred, new Size(5, 5), 0);

        Mat thresh = new();
        CvInvoke.AdaptiveThreshold(blurred, thresh, 255, AdaptiveThresholdType.MeanC, ThresholdType.BinaryInv, 11, 2);

        Mat kernel = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size(2, 2), new Point(-1, -1));
        CvInvoke.Dilate(thresh, thresh, kernel, new Point(-1, -1), 1, BorderType.Reflect, default(MCvScalar));
        CvInvoke.Erode(thresh, thresh, kernel, new Point(-1, -1), 1, BorderType.Reflect, default(MCvScalar));

        CvInvoke.Imwrite(Path.Join(Path.GetTempPath(), "output_thresh.png"), thresh);

        var contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        Mat hierarchy = new();
        CvInvoke.FindContours(thresh, contours, hierarchy, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

        VectorOfPoint? cardContour = null;
        double largestArea = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
        {
            VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i];
            double area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour);
            VectorOfPoint approxContour = new();
            double epsilon = CvInvoke.ArcLength(contour, true) * 0.02;
            CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(contour, approxContour, epsilon, true);

            if (approxContour.Size == 4 && CvInvoke.IsContourConvex(approxContour) && area > largestArea)
            {
                largestArea = area;
                cardContour = approxContour;
            }

        }

        if (cardContour == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No card found");
        }

        Point[] sortedPoints = SortedPoints(cardContour.ToArray());

        PointF[] src = { sortedPoints[0], sortedPoints[1], sortedPoints[2], sortedPoints[3] };
        PointF[] dst = { new(0, 0), new(800, 0), new(0, 1120), new(800, 1120) };
        var transform = CvInvoke.GetPerspectiveTransform(src, dst);

        var output = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.WarpPerspective(image, output, transform, new System.Drawing.Size(800, 1120));

        CvInvoke.DrawContours(temp, new VectorOfVectorOfPoint(cardContour), 0, new MCvScalar(0,255,0,255));
        CvInvoke.Imwrite(Path.Join(Path.GetTempPath(), "output_contour.png"), temp);
        CvInvoke.Imwrite(Path.Join(Path.GetTempPath(), "output.png"), output);
        
        return output;
    }
```

Here are the relevant debug images:

- [Original](https://imgur.com/CMStC3X)
- [Threshold applied](https://imgur.com/WWVDKTq)
- [Contour](https://imgur.com/pFAGUri)
- [Output](https://imgur.com/07vQi89)

As you can see, there is some significant errors in the contour. I'd like to get the output as close to perfect as possible.

I have looked at various OpenCV functions like MinAreaRect, which does a good job of aligning one edge of the card, but does not help with the perspective issues. I have tried different epsilon values for ApproxPolyDP but it did not improve the edge detection as I hoped. I believe the problem is related to the rounded corners.

Comment: As a general recommendation, it might be more effective trying to improve the input data than the processing. It should be fairly simple to create a box with a hole for the camera, and thin paper sides, or diffuse plastic, to provide diffuse light. Having a good initial perspective and white, untextured, background should help immensely.

Comment: rounded corners are a problem for approxPolyDP. OpenCV has no algorithms to extract straight line segments from contours. you could write one yourself. or take ideas from localization of AR markers. they are square, which is a special case of rectangle.

Comment: @JonasH I appreciate the input and understand that better input data is ideal. I expect users to use their phone to scan cards on desks and binders, so what I posted here is probably best case scenario.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Can you explain what AR markers are? I am considering how to write an algorithm to use the data from the FindContours step, though this is pretty far outside my wheelhouse. I am aware that there are other line finding algorithms like HoughLines, but I've had limited success with that.

Comment: forget hough. extremely bad idea. never ever touch that for any reason. that's the best heuristic for beginners.